# Visual Studio 2017 unrecognised database format. Trying to add a access conection

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to make a program that needs a database to work so I followed this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/data-tools/connect-to-data-in-an-access-database-windows-forms

But when I reach step 9, It gives an error: [image]

I already installed the Access Database engine. and it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have both the 32- and the 64-bit version of the database engine installed? Are you sure the database is valid (uncorrupted)?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth When i try to install the 64-bit it gives me this message: http://imgur.com/a/Q0RVA

Comment: Well, there's your problem probably. You need 64-bits Access for 64-bits programs. You can try downloading a recent version of the Access runtime [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040), it has less compatibility problems with other Office versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is missing Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

You can get it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: That link brings me to the accces database engine, and I have already installed that.

Comment: which office suite are you using?

Comment: I'm using office 365

Comment: I uninstalled my previous version of office because it was a 32bit version, now I installed the 64bit version and ran the database engine again, it now gives a different error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the saved connection is not using the right provider.
Right click your connection in the `Server Explorer`, choose `Modify Connection`, click `Change`, and select one you have installed related to `OLE DB` from the dropdown.

Comment: The database file is stored locally on my computer

Comment: @BenjaminCelis that's menu in VS2017

Comment: I'm making a new connection, and OLE DB is selected as the provider